# use getObject() from forge-api npm, how to make the return result as a download link?

Tags: excel, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am using [forge-api](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/HEAD/docs/ObjectsApi.md#getObject) getObject() to download the excel from BIM360 hub. I set up express sever in the backend and make the call in the frontend.

I could get the result of the object and it looks like this:
[image]

So my question is:
How can I convert the result as a download link correctly? I could download the excel, but the excel can not be opened...
[image]

My code looks like this:

**backend**:
[image]

**frontend**:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to modify in your **backend** code is to return **content.body**, instead of **content**
See e.g. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-derivatives-explorer/blob/master/routes/data.management.js#L296

It might even be better if you generated a **pre-signed URL** for the file and passed that to the client. In that case, the file would not be downloaded to your server first and then to the client, but directly to the client in a single step.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-signed-POST/

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Such a small detail saved my day! After I adjust the backend code, it works!

The reason why I set up a backend instead of using sign url is because the file I want to download is stored in BIM360 instead of bucket. And it looks like I can not create sign url if I am not the bucket owner.